# PHP strtotime() different results of monday this week

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a problem getting the date of monday in the current week.

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('monday this week'));
```

When I'm running the above code on my local machine (PHP 5.3) it outputs correctly '2011-03-07', but the same code on my server (PHP 5.2) outputs '2011-03-14' (that's monday next week).

I've tried to run date('W') on both machines and I get the same result (10).

Edit: Any ideas how get this work correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: only assumption is maybe you define start of the week differently...

Comment: Set your server's date to to be correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I've seen exactly this problem, but I've seen ones very similar.  strtotime seems to change behaviour between different versions of PHP, and barring the simple operations (eg. '+1 week'), it's difficult to guarantee that functionality will remain the same.

If you're not able to upgrade to 5.3, which as correctly pointed out does seem to be an improvement, all I can recommend, is playing with some permutations.  It's often possible to get the right answer out of older versions of strtotime by rephrasing the question.  Examples might include ...

- next monday -1 week
- last monday +1 week
- this monday

Answer (score 8):

Use
`date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date('o-\\WW')));`

Comment: Life saver. Especially if you cannot upgrade to php 5.3.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, interpretation of strings in strtotime improved significantly in 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command "date" from the cli prompt on the server and your local desktop. This will verify if the OS is seeing the same date on both systems.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices: either avoid using this function of check if the date is in the future, if yes you decement it by 7 days. Welcome to the wolderful world of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

"Be aware that you cannot rely on this function alone to validate a date, as it will accept insane dates like the 31st of February.

Also, the '... week' functionality by itself may not do what you expect. If used on a Sunday, 'next week' will not return a timestamp of the next Monday, but of the Monday after that. Similarly, a timestamp for the Monday of the current week is returned when 'previous/last week' is used and 'this week' returns a stamp of the Monday of the next week (i.e. the following day). This is not the 'week starts on Sunday' effect, as that would mean all the timestamps returned would have to be on a Sunday and none of them are."

Ff today is sunday, you will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that works (actually the only one that worked for me):

```
$mondayOfWeek = date ('d M Y', strtotime($someDate) - ((date ('N', strtotime($someDate)) - 1) * 3600 * 24));
```

Comment: Super delayed response, but for anyone else like me who sees this, this isn't daylight saving proof. 48 hours before 2018-09-30 in NZ is 2018-09-27, not the 28th. Using strtotime with "-x days" would be a better bet.

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = strtotime('This week monday 8 am');
echo $this->unix_timestamp_to_human($today,"D M j G:i:s T Y");
```